# Regex: ignore extra characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to figure out how to detect extra characters within a spam word like:

`pha.rmacy` or `vi*agra`

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a (dis)similarity metric, such as [**edit distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). For instance, the edit distance between *vi.agra* and *viagra* is 1.

Then, you determine that a given word is the same as the spam word, if the edit distance between them is below a certain threshold like, say, 2.

But if you really want to use a regex, you can use something like `/[^a-zA-Z0-9-\s]/` to remove punctuation from the word. But then again, you would fail to identify something like `viZagra` as being the same word as `viagra`.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions do not seem like the appropriate tool for figuring this out.  But as an attempt to answer it just because it is interesting, a simple way would be to do something like this:

```
/v.?i.?a.?g.?r.?a/
```

It would match 0 or 1 characters between each letter.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how broadly you want to match. The following will match any contiguous sequence of non-whitespace-or-word-characters interspersed among those letters:

```
/p[^\s\w]*h[^\s\w]*a[^\s\w]*r[^\s\w]*m[^\s\w]*a[^\s\w]*c[^\s\w]*y/
```

You can build this regex in code. E.g., in Perl:

```
$re = join("[^\\s\\w]*", split("", "pharmacy"))
```

Ultimately, regexes probably won't satisfy all your requirements, though.